# Issues with page being larger than it needs to be; React.js

Tags: html, css, reactjs, web

The current page looks like this:[image]
As you can see there is a lot of blank space at the top. I can't seem to figure out how to make that blank space go away. Here is the HTML:

```
<div className="auth-form-container" style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center', height: '100%'}}>
            <img src={logo} alt="VaporCode Logo"></img>
            <h2 style={{ color: 'white' }}>Register</h2>
        <form className="register-form" onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label htmlFor="firstname" style={{ color: 'white' }}>First Name</label>
            <input value={firstname} firstname="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name" />
            <label htmlFor="lastname" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Last Name</label>
            <input value={lastname} lastname="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name" />
            <label htmlFor="email" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Email</label>
            <input value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}type="email" placeholder="Email" id="email" name="email" />
            <label htmlFor="username" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Userame</label>
            <input value={username} username="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" />
            <label htmlFor="password" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Password</label>
            <input value={pass} onChange={(e) => setPass(e.target.value)} type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password" name="password" />
            <label htmlFor="repeatpassword" style={{ color: 'white' }}>Retype Password</label>
            <input value={reppass} onChange={(e) => setrepPass(e.target.value)} type="password" placeholder="Retype Password" id="repeatpassword" nam>
            <button type="submit">Register</button>
        </form>
        <linkbutton className="link-btn" onClick={() => props.onFormSwitch('login')}>Already have an account? Login here.</linkbutton>
        <div style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center" }}>
            <iframe src="https://www.guilded.gg/canvas_index.html?route=%2Fcanvas%2Fembed%2Fbadge%2F4R5YgKWR" width="294" height="48" frameborder="0">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Please not that since some of the functions are long, the code did not copy correctly, due to me programming over SSH. If someone has a better solution, it would be much appreciated. (I am running a vps without a ui)
Here is the CSS:

```
App {
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #000000;
  background-image: linear-gradient(79deg, #073a8c, #281369 48%, #135b69);
}

.auth-form-container, .login-form, .register-form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 600px)  {
  .auth-form-container {
    position:absolute;   
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    border: solid #222222;
    background-color: #000000;
    fill: solid #000000;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin:30rem;
  }
}

label {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.25rem 0;
}
input {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
}


button {
  border: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(79deg, #ff893f, #fa8d90 48%, #e769d1);
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-weight : bold;
  transition-duration: 2s;
}


linkbutton {
  border: none;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.link-btn {
  background: none;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
img {
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

I am programming this in react.js.

I tried forcing the position to be absolute, but it made the page look wonky on smaller screens. In the end I want the login container to be close to the top of the screen. Please keep in mind, I don't want this to be in the CSS, I want this in the HTML if possible.

Also, if anyone has recommendations for programming remotely not via ssh please hit me up! ;)

-Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are centering content with flexbox, with `App` selector, and then setting `.auth-form-container` to have a `height: 100%` is going to fill the entire container height, so the `30rem` margin-top could be eliminated. Try this, if it's not working please attach a working snippet so we can see the real issue. Hope it helps!

Comment: I like the horizontal margin, and want to keep it, but I need to change the vertical margin, and am not sure how.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by working snippet

Comment: Change `margin:30rem;` to `margin: 0 30rem;`

Comment: BTW here's an example of a code snippet https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do